# Nomenclature tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Is it possible to add `nomenclature` tag? I needed it for [Meaning of Sadhu, Sant, Rishi and Muni](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/meaning-of-sadhu-santsaint-and-rishi)

Comment: May I know why do you want to introduce that tag?

Comment: @Mr.Alien for questions that ask for `definitions of terms`.

Comment: I've added **definition** tag to your question which will make more sense..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The one tag cleanup post to rule them all](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/470/the-one-tag-cleanup-post-to-rule-them-all)